# Gmail - Link to Draft in non-conversation view

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am importing/creating drafts in Gmail using the Gmail API. After creation I'd like to redirect the user to the Gmail UI with the opened Draft in the composer window.

I made it work properly for [https://mail.google.com/mail/#drafts?compose=[MESSAGE](https://mail.google.com/mail/#drafts?compose=%5BMESSAGE) ID]. Other urls I found here also worked well. Gmail is doing some redirects and eventually the composer window is opened with the draft.

Now my issue:

If the user has not enabled **"Conversation view"** this will not work at all. The redirect will then result in https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=new and only an empty, new composer window is shown and a new draft is created by the UI.

If I open the draft directly the ID-format is different. https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=hJzgZpSqgLQcCWgZqnlNRzRBfMbjZVnZklzvcFxhQCdwT... and I have no idea if this format can be generated somehow.

Does anybody has an idea or experience to also make it work with this UI setting. How I can force Gmail to load the draft into the composer window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### If you have Email Threading > Conversation View enabled

Make use of the following URL

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=DRAFT_MESSAGE_ID
```

### If you have disabled the Email Threading > Conversation View option

Make use of the following URL

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/DRAFT_MESSAGE_ID
```

### Additional information

- The main difference between them is that the first is treated as a conversation while the second example is not.
- You can use **#drafts** instead of **#inbox** in the URL.
- The number after **.../mail/u/** is the session you have opened
- You can retrieve the DRAFT_MESSAGE_ID by making a [request to the API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/list)
- You can approximately generate the compose ID by yourself, there are some examples out there (not recommended). I strongly recommend you to use the DRAFT_MESSAGE_ID instead.

Comment: Thanks Jose for the comprehensive answer. Unfortunately the second Url does not even open the composer window in my case. It just opens the list (inbox or drafts) after doing some redirects. By DRAFT_MESSAGE_ID you mean the Id of the Message inside the draft object? Is there any use of the Draft Id?

Comment: By draft message id I mean the message ID. If you are not able to open the draft message I recommend you to get help by opening Gmail and going to **Help > Send feedback** . By doing so explain that you can't open the draft message using both of the URLs mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to still be an issue the one solution I did find was that you can find your draft directly (even though it would be the last draft) and go through multiple accounts by redirecting to

[https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?authuser={user](https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?authuser=%7Buser) account}&Email={email account}&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/#search/rfc822msgid:CAMU-31NcJCVHyGNsAycRKfuS0nMonoaZ6wFMD90Sej996qjuPQ@mail.gmail.com

You need to get your message id toi replace the area from <> from your draft.  So you'll have to create the draft first.  Get the google message ID, then use that with messages/get to get the Global Message Id (also referred to as message id) and then use that with a search.  At this point you'll open a page with a search to a single draft but it will not be opened.  Your users will have to click on the one message.  Unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to have the good way work for conversation view, and this way work for non.

I tried many different URLS and nothing worked.  As noted in the original question, it might work that you could link to the full URL but I see no way to get that.  If you spend long enough working with an email you'll even find that ID changes so they aren't even stable within a single day.

Another solution that could work is as explained:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/DRAFT_MESSAGE_ID

But as noted this does not open the draft on the first time you go there.  It seems you have to travel to that link 2 times in a row to get the message to appear.  I guess you could go to the page maybe inject some javascript to go to the page again but I don't know how to do that.